# Ellipse using least squares

Tags: matlab, contour

```
x = [1.02 .95 .87 .77 .67 .56 .44 .30 .16 .01]';
y = [0.39 .32 .27 .22 .18 .15 .13 .12 .13 .15]';

% function Ax = b
N = numel(x);
A = [x.^2 x.*y y.^2 x y];
b = [-1*ones(N,1)];

%coeffs = [a b c d e]';
coeffs = A\b; 

a = coeffs(1)
b = coeffs(2);
c = coeffs(3);
d = coeffs(4);
e = coeffs(5);

plot(x,y, 'bo')
hold on

% prepare contour plot
xmin = min(x);
xmax = max(x);
ymin = min(y);
ymax = max(y);
%set deltas 
deltay = .001;
deltax = .001;
%create arrays X and Y
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xmin:deltax:xmax,ymin:deltay:ymax);
% evaluate quadratic form 
Z = a*X.^2 + b*X.*Y + c*Y.^2 + d*X + e*Y +f;
% plot where Z =0. line
contour(X,Y,Z,[0,0])
title('Planetary Orbit');
```

I am trying to am trying to make an ellipse but the code is making a parabola. I assume it is from the way that I am setting up my contour plot. If someone could give me some direction on what needs to be changed that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `surf` plot also looks parabola. Are you sure it's not a math problem?

Comment: I get this: `Undefined function or variable 'f'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `plot(x,y)`, you'll see that the input data is only of a fraction of an orbit. Because you set the limits of your plot (`xmin`, `xmax`, etc) to the bounding box of your input data, your plot will only show the portion of the ellipse within this bounding box.

Simply enlarging the bounding box will show the full ellipse:

```
% OP's code here
f = 1;
xmin = -0.6; % enlarge the bounding box
xmax = 1.2;
ymin = 0;
ymax = 1.3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xmin:deltax:xmax,ymin:deltay:ymax);
Z = a*X.^2 + b*X.*Y + c*Y.^2 + d*X + e*Y +f;
contour(X,Y,Z,[0,0])
axis equal
hold on
plot(x,y,'r.') % Data points on top of the ellipse
```